# SWT Tree Item Height

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

Is it possible to have an SWT tree with lines of different height ?

Manuel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a SWT tree or table the items cannot different heights. If you need to make every row with different height, you must use a custom widget, like [KTable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ktable/) or [nebula grid](http://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/grid/grid.php) for example.

Comment: Is this written in the API reference ? I can't find any information about this anywhere beside your comment. Regards.

Comment: @SimonPA, I think it's not possible because the operating system's table doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could of course call `setFont()` on the `TreeItem` in question, and give it a larger font than that used by the other `TreeItem` rows.  However, this may not be what you want... having multiple font sizes in the `Tree`.

A second more hack-y alternative might be to instead use the `setImage()` method on `TreeItem`... setting a white (or whatever) background image for each row, with the taller rows using a bigger image than the shorter rows.

This second approach would give you custom row heights without changing the fonts, although you would want to be sure to choose a background image of the same color as the system default background color.  Perhaps you could even create your `Image` objects programmatically in-memory to ensure this.

Comment: The image hack is a nice idea. Does it work?  I recall trying to achieve something similar some time ago and never found a solution that works across all platforms. This is the kind of hacks that might not work well on all SWT implementations, so make sure you carefully test it.

Comment: Does this solution really gives different height for each row ? Today I tried an other solution with a Measure Listener: it works but sets all the rows to the tallest height. Why this is different when using images of different sizes ?

Comment: It does not work on macOS (10.13), I just tried it. All rows are adjusted accordingly. I think the operating system limitations might be the reason that apps like OmniOutliner have their own tree implementation.

Answer (score 0):

At least under Linux with GTK the following makes the first TreeItem larger than the other:

```
tree.addListener(SWT.MeasureItem, new Listener() {
    boolean first = true;

    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        if (event.item instanceof TreeItem) {
            if (first) {
                event.height = event.height * 3;
                first = false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but there seems to be a minimum size for a tree item so if sou try to set is smaller it has no effect.